# Ruby Closures: How to return args and block as a single argument to pass to a method

Tags: ruby, closures

Suppose I have a method that takes args and a block:

```
def yield_if_widget(*args, &block)
  if args[0].is_a?(Widget)
    block.call
  end
end
```

I can call this method with arguments and a block:

```
yield_if_widget(Widget.new) do
  puts "I like widgets"
end
```

But what if I have another method that prepares the arguments and the block:

```
def widget_and_block
  args = [Widget.new]
  block = proc{ puts "I like widgets" }

  [args, block]
end
```

And I want to be able to pass it directly to the first method:

```
yield_if_widget(*widget_and_block)
```

Is this possible?  How?  Assume that `yield_if_widget` is defined in a library and monkey-patching it is not an option.

Comment: The correct answer for your question is "No, It is not possible".

Answer (score 2):

To make ruby understand that the parameter in a call to a method is a block, a *commercial and* must be put in front of it.

```
def widget_and_block
  args = [Widget.new]
  block = proc{ puts "I like widgets" }
  [args, block]
end

wab = widget_and_block
#                           ⇓
yield_if_widget(*wab.first, &wab.last)
```

Oneliner (it won’t return what `yiw` returns):

```
widget_and_block.tap { |args, cb| yield_if_widget *args, &cb }
```

**UPD** Basically, ampersand in method call is used to say “hey, convert this to proc and use as codeblock” to ruby. It’s a syntax part of the language, like you have to put array content inside square brackets, not curly. That’s why an ampersand should exist in the source code.

On the other hand, whether you were free to modify the `yield_if_widget` **and remove ampersand** from parameter list:

```
-def yield_if_widget(*args, &block)
+def yield_if_widget(*args, block)
```

the code would work as expected, since the proc instance is passed as the last parameter and calling `call` method on it is very naturally permitted.

Please also note, that prepending an ampersand to the last parameter to method call forces `#to_proc` method to be called on it, like in:

```
[1,2,3].reduce &:+
#⇒ 6
```

The magic above works because `Symbol` class has it’s own implementation of `#to_proc` method.

Comment: "Ampersand in method call is used to say “hey, convert this to proc and use as codeblock” to ruby" -- I want to understand why it matters *where* I put the ampersand.  Why, for instance, can't `widget_and_block` return `[args, &block]` (instead of `[args, block]`)?  Furthermore, block already *is* a Proc, so shouldn't I really need to tell the method "Accept this proc as a proc and not as a regular argument"?  Is that really what the "&" is doing there?

Comment: Yes, it is. All that stuff is around resolving `yyield keyword.

Comment: You answer is misleading then.  If you edit it to explain the Ampersand more precisely (ideally with a link to some more detailed explanation), I will mark this answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it in one line (as far as I can tell). You need temporary variables.

given these methods:

```
def prepare
  return [4, proc { puts "called" }]
end

def run(a, &block)
  puts a
  block.call
end
```

You can pass the return values from `prepare` to your method like so:

```
i,blk = prepare()
run(i, &blk)
```